# startTypeError: daemon.getblockcount is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi javascript is not my Language but here goes  I've googled this and tried fixes suggested but still not working I get a startTypeError: daemon.getblockcount is not a function
at Object. (/home/seed3/Checkpoint-Generator/checkpoint_generator.js:20:8)

This the code page:<=

```
const fs = require('fs'),
      { TurtleCoind } = require('turtlecoin-rpc');


const daemon = new TurtleCoind({
    host: 'qbitconnect.com', // ip address or hostname of the host
    port: 20101, // what port is the RPC server running on
    timeout: 5000, // request timeout
    ssl: false // whether we need to connect using SSL/TLS
});

class Checkpoint {
    constructor(height, hash) {
        this.height = height;
        this.hash = hash;
    }
}

var checkpoints = [];

daemon.getblockcount().then(async (height) => {
    console.log("Got blockheight " + height + "!");

    for (let i = 1; i < height; i++) {
        console.log("Getting block info for height " + i);

        const blockHash = await daemon.blockHeaderByHeight(i)

        checkpoints.push(new Checkpoint(i - 1, blockHash));
    }

    console.log('Got', checkpoints.length, 'checkpoints from 0 to', checkpoints[checkpoints.length - 1].height, 'blocks');

    let csv = ''

    for (const checkpoint of checkpoints) {
        csv += `${checkpoint.height},${checkpoint.hash}\n`
    }

    const buffer = Buffer.from(csv, 'ascii');

    fs.open('checkpoints.csv', 'w', (err, fd) => {
        if (err) throw err

        console.log('Opened checkpoints.csv!');

        fs.write(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.byteLength, 0, (err, bytes) => {
            if(err) throw err;

            console.log('Wrote', Math.floor(bytes / 1024), ' kilobytes');

            fs.close(fd, (err) => {
                console.log('Closed checkpoints.csv!');
            });
        });
    })
})
.catch((error) => {
    throw new Error(`An error occurred whilst getting height of the blockchain : ${error}`);
});
```

generates the current checkpoints.csv file from a daemon and saves it to disk
Any help and suggestions would be most welcome guys thanks